# Advantages/Disadvantages of increasing AppPool Timeout on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, azure

I am just about to launch my ASP.NET MVC3 web app to production, however, as a complex app, it takes a **LONG** time to start up. Obviously, I don't want my users waiting over a minute for their first request to go through after the AppPool has timed out.

From my research, i've found that there are two ways to combat this:

**Run a worker role or other process** - which poll's the website every 19 minutes preventing the warm up.

**Change the timeout from the default 20 minutes** - To something much larger.

As Solution 2 seems like the better idea, i just wondered what the disadvantages would be of this, will I run out of memory etc.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd change the timeout, but both should work: effectively they would both have the same effect of preventing the worker processes from shutting down.

I believe the timeout is there to avoid IIS retaining resources that aren't needed for servers with lots of Web sites that are lightly used. Given that heavily used sites (like this one!) don't shut down their worker processes I don't think you'll see any memory issues.

Comment: If SO don't need to recycle their IIS worker processes, nor do I! Thanks i'll go ahead with this.

Answer (score 3):

Could you use the auto-start feature of IIS?  There is a post [here](http://windowsazurecat.com/2010/10/how-using-appfabric-auto-start-feature-to-avoid-warm-up-delays-for-iis-hosted-wcf-receive-locations/) that presents this idea.

You'd have IIS 7.5 and Win2k8 R2 with Azure OS family 2.  You'd just need to be able to script/automate any setup steps and configuration.

Comment: Thanks very much! i'd never heard of this new Auto-Start feature. I think I will use this combined with extending the timeout to achieve the best performance.

Answer (score 2):

I do this with a background thread that requests a keepalive URL every 15 minutes.  Not only does this keep the app from going idle, but it also warms up the app right away anytime the web role or virtual machine restarts or is rebuilt.

This is all possible because Web Roles really are just Worker Roles that also do IIS stuff.  So you can still use all the standard Worker Role startup hooks in a Web Role.

I got the idea from [this blog post](http://www.bondigeek.com/blog/2011/10/26/simple-azure-warmup-task/) but tweaked the code to do a few extra warmup tasks.

First, I have a class that inherits from RoleEntryPoint (it does some other things besides this warm up task and I removed them for simplicity):

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    // other unrelated member variables appear here...

    private WarmUp _warmUp;

    public override bool OnStart()
    {

        // other startup stuff appears here...

        _warmUp = new WarmUp();
        _warmUp.Start();
        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

All the actual warm up logic is in this WarmUp class.  When it first runs it hits a handful of URLs on the local instance IP address (vs the public, load balanced hostname) to get things in memory so that the first people to use it get the fastest possible response time.  Then, it loops and hits a single keepalive URL (again on the local role instance) that doesn't do any work and just serves to make sure that IIS doesn't shut down the application pool as idle.

```
public class WarmUp
{
    private Thread worker;

    public void Start()
    {
        worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
        worker.IsBackground = true;
        worker.Start();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        var endpoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["http"]; // "http" has to match the endpointName in your ServiceDefinition.csdef file.

        var pages = new string[] 
        { 
            "/",
            "/help",
            "/signin",
            "/register",
            "/faqs"
        }; 

        foreach (var page in pages)
        {
            try
            {
                var address = String.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}{3}",
                    endpoint.Protocol,
                    endpoint.IPEndpoint.Address,
                    endpoint.IPEndpoint.Port,
                    page);
                var webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadString(address);
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Warmed {0}", address));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        var keepalive = String.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}{3}",
            endpoint.Protocol,
            endpoint.IPEndpoint.Address,
            endpoint.IPEndpoint.Port,
            "/keepalive");

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadString(keepalive);
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Pinged {0}", keepalive));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //absorb
            }
            Thread.Sleep(900000); // 15 minutes
        }
    }
}
```